# Cosmos db to store and retrieve thousands of documents with in seconds

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am storing millions of documents in cosmos db with proper partitionkey. I need to retrieve say 500,000 documents to do some calculations and display the output in UI , this should happen with in say 10 second.
Would this be possible? I have tried this but taking nearly a minute. So for this kind of requirement is this the correct approach?

```
"id": "Latest_100_Sku1_1496188800",
    "PartitionKey": "Latest_100_Sku1
    "SnapshotType": 2,
    "AccountCode": "100",
    "SkuCode": "Sku1",
    "Date": "2017-05-31T00:00:00",
    "DateEpoch": 1496188800,
    "Body": "rVNBa4MwFP4v72xHElxbvYkbo4dBwXaX0UOw6ZRFIyaBFfG/7zlT0EkPrYUcku+9fO/7kvca"
```

Size of one document : 825 byte

Am using autoscale 4000 Throughput

Query statistics - am using 2 queries.

Query 1  - select * from c where c.id in ({ids})
here i use PartitionKey in Query options.

Query Statistics
METRIC
VALUE
Request Charge
102.11 RUs
Showing Results
1 - 100
Retrieved document count More information
200
Retrieved document size More information
221672 bytes
Output document count More information
200
Output document size More information
221972 bytes
Index hit document count More information
200
Index lookup time More information
17.0499 ms
Document load time More information
1.59 ms
Query engine execution time More information
0.3401 ms
System function execution time More information
0.060000000000000005 ms
User defined function execution time More information
0 ms
Document write time More information
0.16 ms
Round Trips
1

Query 2 --
select * from c where c.PartitionKey in ({keys}) and c.DateEpoch>={startDate.ToEpoch()} and c.DateEpoch<={endDate.ToEpoch()}

Query Statistics
METRIC
VALUE
Request Charge
226.32 RUs
Showing Results
1 - 100
Retrieved document count More information
200
Retrieved document size More information
176580 bytes
Output document count More information
200
Output document size More information
176880 bytes
Index hit document count More information
200
Index lookup time More information
88.31 ms
Document load time More information
4.2399000000000004 ms
Query engine execution time More information
0.4701 ms
System function execution time More information
0.060000000000000005 ms
User defined function execution time More information
0 ms
Document write time More information
0.19 ms
Round Trips
1

Comment: There is not enough information necessary to answer this question. Please include a sample document in your container, the query you are trying to run, the partition key for your container, the amount of RU/s provisioned and the output from the Data Explorer showing the query stats.

Comment: I have edited the details with all the things you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Query #1 looks fine. Query #2 most likely would benefit from a composite index on DateEpoch. I'm not sure what the UDF is but if you're converting dates to epoch you want to read a new blog post [New date and time system functions in Azure Cosmos DB](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/new-date-and-time-system-functions/)

Overall, retrieving 500K documents in 1-2 queries to do some calculations seems like a strange use case. Typically most people will pre-calculate values and persist them using a materialized view pattern using [change feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-design-patterns). Depending on how often you run these two queries, this is often a more efficient use of compute resources.

Comment: Thanks Mark, i tried composite index on DateEpoch but did not help much. I cant store the pre calculated results because my scenario is the user can select any date range from 4 years and i shud load documents for those selected dates and do the calculation. I increased the throughput but did not improve. When i moved the service to P3V2 thats better app plan with more computing power am getting better response. I am calling those 2 queries parallelly.

Comment: This scenario is better suited for Synapse Link than for Cosmos DB. Cosmos is an operational database, more suited for high volume OLTP than it is for large OLAP type queries. I would take a look at Synapse Link and see if that is a better fit for you.